# Opening developer page on Huawei AppGallery where shown all apps of that developer

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Is there a way to open developer page on Huawei AppGallery where shown all apps of that developer?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to My Apps to see all the apps under your developer's account. The steps are as follows:

1. Sign in to your Huawei developer's account: [Sign in](https://id7.cloud.huawei.com/CAS/portal/loginAuth.html?reqClientType=89&loginChannel=89000060&countryCode=us&loginUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fid7.cloud.huawei.com%3A443%2FCAS%2Fportal%2FloginAuth.html&lang=en-us&themeName=red&clientID=6099200&state=7463135&service=https%3A%2F%2Foauth-login7.cloud.huawei.com%2Foauth2%2Fv2%2FloginCallback%3Faccess_type%3Doffline%26client_id%3D6099200%26display%3Dpage%26flowID%3D83a07ca9-69d0-47a2-811f-b0ff146ab5fb%26h%3D1657553220.7600%26lang%3Den-us%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdeveloper.huawei.com%252Fconsumer%252Fen%252Flogin%252Fhtml%252FhandleLogin.html%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Fcountry%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Fbase.profile%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Floginid%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Faccount.flags%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Frealname%252Fstate%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Frealname%252Fidentity%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Frealname%252Fctf.type%2Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.huawei.com%252Fauth%252Faccount%252Fstate.register%26state%3D7463135%26v%3D170b908833136471acb320da92a1558eea8b1d241c3a0fd39a072f1e79521324&validated=true)

[image]

2. Choose App Services:

[image]

3. Choose AppGallery Connect:

[image]

4. Choose My Apps:

[image]

5. Now you can see all your apps in AppGallery:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Huawei's AppGallery takes a different approach and doesn't have public developer profile pages like other app stores. Developers can only see their full app list when logged into their account, not publicly viewable to users or other developers. The only option is to search for the apps individually.